# Factoring $(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)+(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)$ and use the result to solve an equation

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I managed to prove that $(x+a+b+c)$ is a factor of
$$(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)+(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)$$

Then I was asked to use the result to solve
$$(x+2)(x-3)(x-1)+4=0$$

I know by comparison, $a=2, b=-3, c=-1$, and thus $(x-2)$ is a factor, but I can't really figure out how to solve the equation without expanding the brackets.

Comment: Considering the other roots are $\pm \sqrt 5$, I can't imagine you'd be intended to do anything else but to expand the expression, divide by $(x-2)$, and find the roots of the quadratic that results.

Comment: And the other factor is given by $$x^2-5$$

Comment: Also, the solutions are $x=2, x=\sqrt{5}, x=-\sqrt{5}$

Comment: Yes, this is true.

Comment: So my only viable solution is to expand and factor?

Comment: Feels like it, yeah. This method by itself can only grant you an integer solution to your given cubic equation. Since the other two solutions are irrational, that's about as good as can be done here. I guess the main use of the fact is that, *a priori*, looking a cubic it's often hard to discern what exactly the roots are, and the cubic formula is a pain to use. At least this method ensures that, if you can factor the cubic in this manner, you're immediately given a solution, and then in turn can do some basic polynomial division to get the much more pleasant quadratic.

Comment: How hard is expanding the brackets - you have identified a factor of a cubic and what remains will be a quadratic. Practically that is a quick way through.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you do have to expand the brackets.

Fortunately, it's not so messy after all:

$$(x+2)(x-3)(x-1)+4=0$$

so

$$x^3-2x^2-5x+10=0$$
and factoring our $x-2$, 
$$(x-2)(x^2-5)=0$$

from which we can readily read the answer as $x=2,\pm\sqrt{5}$

Comment: You actually *don't* have to expand the brackets if you spot a few tricks. I explain it in my answer.

Comment: @J.G. Strictly speaking, your answer does expand most of the brackets, it just expands them one at a time after dividing $x-2$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the $x^2$ coefficient in your cubic is $a+b+c$, the quadratic factor is of the form $x^2+k$, with the roots being $\pm\sqrt{-k}$. The $x=0$ case gives $$k=\frac{abc+(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)}{a+b+c}=ab+bc+ca.$$In your case $k=-5$.

Simplifying $k$ as above *looks* like it requires tedious algebra, but things aren't as bad as they seem. It's the ratio of two fully symmetric polynomials in $a,\,b,\,c$, one of degree $3$, the other $1$. This doesn't prove on its own that $k$ is a polynomial; but if it is, it must be fully symmetric and of degree $2$, and hence proportional to $ab+bc+ca$. The case $a=b=c$ gives $k=\frac{9a^3}{3a}=3a^2$, so it'll have to be $ab+bc+ca$ itself. So it makes sense to double-check whether $(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+c)=abc+(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)$. But *of course* it does, because both sides are fully symmetric cubic functions, so they have a fixed ratio. Again, the case $a=b=c$ strengthens this to equality.

Answer (score 1):

It is good that you managed to factor!

Here is one way to do it:
$$(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)+(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)=\\
x^3+(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+bc+ca)x+abc+\\
2abc+a^2b+ab^2+a^2c+ac^2+b^2c+bc^2=\\
x^2(x+a+b+c)+(ab+bc+ca)x+\\
ab(a+b+c)+ac(a+b+c)+bc(a+b+c)=\\
x^2(x+a+b+c)+(ab+bc+ca)x+\\
(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)=\\
x^2(x+a+b+c)+(ab+bc+ca)(x+a+b+c)=\\
(x+a+b+c)(x^2+ab+bc+ca).$$
Now, write the given equation in this form:
$$(x+2)(x-3)(x-1)+4=0 \iff \\
(x+2)(x-3)(x-1)+(2-3)(-3-1)(-1+2)=0 \iff \\
(x+2-3-1)(x^2+2(-3)+(-3)(-1)+(-1)2)=0 \iff \\
(x-2)(x^2-5)=0 \Rightarrow x_1=2, x_{2,3}=\pm \sqrt{5}.$$

Comment: This is a good and complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not more efficient than straightforwardly factoring out, but it works as well:

$$\begin{eqnarray}\frac{(x+2)(x−3)(x−1)+4}{x-2} & = & \frac{(x-2+4)(x−3)(x−1)}{x-2}+\frac{4}{x-2} \\
& = & (1+\frac{4}{x-2})(x−3)(x−1)+\frac{4}{x-2} \\
& = & (x−3)(x−1) + \frac{4(x−3)(x−2+1)}{x-2}+\frac{4}{x-2}\\
& = & (x−3)(x−1) + 4(x−3)(1+\frac{1}{x-2})+\frac{4}{x-2}\\
& = & (x−3)(x−1) + 4(x−3) + \frac{4(x−2-1)}{x-2}+\frac{4}{x-2}\\
& = & (x−3)(x−1) + 4(x−3) + 4\\
& = & (x−3)(x+3) + 4\\
& = & x^2 - 5 \; .
\end{eqnarray}$$